# How to implement Roles in ASP.NET Identity in webform

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I successfully created a new user with this code:

```
        protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Default UserStore constructor uses the default connection string named: DefaultConnection
        var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
        var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
        var user = new IdentityUser() { UserName = txtbxUserName.Text };
        IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, txtbxPassword.Text);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            var userIdentity =
               manager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { }, userIdentity);
            Response.Redirect("~/MoneyFly");
        }
        else
        {
            litStatusMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

The code created a local database as soon as the user was created.

I want to create roles and add them to users.

I saw a post such as the one below.

```
https://forums.asp.net/t/2093837.aspx?How+to+implement+Roles+in+ASP+NET+Identity+2+1+in+Webforms
```

And I struggled to replicate what was done in the code.

That is partially, because it includes an autogenerated class, which I dont have.

```
ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

How do I generate that dbContext. It seems to be vital in the usage of the framework.
For example this line of code uses it to create an instance of RoleStore.

```
 var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
```

Comment: ApplicationDbContext is a class type which inherits from DbContext class which is part of EntityFramework. You may want to read up on EntityFramework to make sense of the DbContext

Comment: dan mann, here is a link that may help you achieve most of what you are attempting to build. It was major help to me when I recently built my first account login for my organization. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/MVC-5-with-2FA-email-8f26d952

Comment: I know it is code first. But whats the process of generating a database and then generating that ApplicationDBContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution.

This solution worked for me.

```
            var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>();
        var roleMgr = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
        IdentityResult IdRoleResult = roleMgr.Create(new IdentityRole { Name = "Administrator" });
        var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
        var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
        IdentityResult IdUserResult = manager.AddToRole( manager.FindByName("vi").Id, "Administrator");
```

You dont have to provide a DBContext to the RoleStore Constructor.